# What are the benefits of using an online account with Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-account

I recently installed a copy of Windows 8 on a computer that didn't have connectivity, so I ended up creating an account that was not associated with a Windows Live ID. I am able to see all of the applications that come stock with Windows 8, and update them.

What are some of the benefits or drawbacks of logging in with an online account? Will I be able to use that same online account, even if I don't have connectivity?

Answer (score 5):

While using a Microsoft account, you’ll be able to synchronize some of your PC’s settings between your computers. Many settings here, such as “App settings,” only apply to modern-style apps (formerly known as Metro-style apps). Other sync options, such as your account picture, desktop background, and task-bar configuration are useful to Windows desktop users that use Windows on multiple computers. After you set up Windows once, your settings will be synchronized between every computer you log into with your Microsoft account.

This also allows syncing and sharing personal data across multiple devices very easily. which can be very dangerous if someone gains unauthorized access to your Live account.

Useful links -- 
http://www.howtogeek.com/121975/htg-explains-microsoft-accounts-vs.-local-accounts-in-windows-8/

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/22437/windows-8-use-local-account-instead-microsoft-account-login/

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can use the online account, even if you don't have connectivity. The advantages for me are mainly the syncing of apps, settings, documents, etc. Anything you add to Skydrive for example, will automatically be available on all your Windows 8 devices, but also in the web interface. Same goes for mail, calendar, etc and other apps also.

There's more on [Microsoft's site](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/microsoft-account#1TC=t1).

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Microsoft account to be able to install Windows Store Apps (aka Metro or Modern UI apps).

Of course you can use your online account without network connectivity, however, you have to login with network connection available for the first time so that Windows can check your account password. Then it will be cached.

Or you can use your local account, and switch it to a Microsoft when there's Internet connection.