# Do I really want my Windows login associated with my Live account?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

I recently upgraded to Win 10 and used my same username and password from my previous Windows installation. Earlier today when returning to my PC, it had locked as I had been away for a while but it wasn't recognising my password. I then noticed that Windows seemed to have associated itself with my Live account (I had used the "Store" for the first time today).

What are the benefits / disadvantages to using my Live account? For me its not ideal as my Live password is ridiculously long and complicated (handled by a password manager). I don't really want to have to try to remember this password but I also don't want to have to change my Live password to something 'basic' in comparison to what it is now.

I did go to the Accounts settings in Windows and chose "Sign in with a local account instead" but when I tried to do this it told me "Windows is already using that name. Please enter a different username" and did not let me proceed.

Unless there are any significant benefits, does anyone know how I can revert back to not having my Live account associated with my Windows login?

EDIT: My Live account is not my day-to-day account. It is an old email account which I occasionally use for signing up to forums etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of places document the benefits of using a Microsoft account.  Try [this SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/501410/) or [this HowToGeek article](http://www.howtogeek.com/121975/htg-explains-microsoft-accounts-vs.-local-accounts-in-windows-8/) for starters, and search for "Microsoft account vs local account" to find a lot more.

If you decide you don't want to use the Microsoft Account, you **should** be able to disconnect your local account from Microsoft.  The steps you followed look correct, and I just verified them on my own Windows 10 computer after signing into the Store the same way.  **I'm not sure why that error message appears for you, but you're not the only one**.  [This SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/716107/) was the exact same problem on Windows 8.1.  They ended up choosing a new username and then going into Computer Manager to change it later.

One final thought for next time - you can actually use a Microsoft account to sign into the store *without using it to sign into Windows.*  When you sign into the store, choose the option that says "Sign in to just this app instead.

[image: Sign in to just this app instead]

Answer (score 0):

Having a "Live" account can be beneficial. The Mail Calendar and Contacts (People) tiles require Microsoft credentials. You don't -have- to use those three live tiles. They could simply be there as backups to your regular mail client.

If your login password is annoyingly long, type in "Sign-In Options" from the Start menu and you can assign a four digit Pin which will be associated with your longer password. It's convenient and secure. You could also use a Picture password, but it is a little more trouble to mess with.

Comment: I forgot to mention in the original question too that my Live account is not my daily email account - I use Gmail. It is historic and I occasionally use it for forum signups etc. The PIN option sounds like it could be a winner mind you. I'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

A big plus is that you can't crack the password with tools like ophcrack. If that does not matter to you, I would not recommend it, privacy-wise. (You can log into the Windows store with you M$ account without logging in to Windows.)
If privacy does not matter either, and you have more than one device running Windows 10, do it. It is handy.

Comment: Be **very** careful with this.  Ophcrack will still work fine as long as there are **any** local admin accounts.  And using a Microsoft account could actually be **less secure** than a local account, since that password can be reset by anyone with access to a linked email account or mobile phone.